# GemLoadError when installing documentcloud from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install documentcloud from GitHub and I'm having a number of issues with the installation. I got through the installation but am now getting:

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate actionpack-2.3.14, because rack-1.4.1 conflicts with rack (~> 1.1.0) (Gem::LoadError)

My Gem List is:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.0)
calais (0.0.13)
cloud-crowd (0.6.2)
curb (0.8.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.8)
docsplit (0.6.3)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hpricot (0.8.6)
jammit (0.6.5)
json (1.7.3)
libxml-ruby (2.3.2)
mime-types (1.18)
nokogiri (1.5.4)
open4 (1.3.0)
passenger (3.0.13)
pg (0.13.2)
Platform (0.4.0)
POpen4 (0.1.4)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
rack (1.4.1, 1.1.3)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rest-client (1.6.7)
right_aws (3.0.4)
right_http_connection (1.3.0)
rsolr (1.0.8)
rubygems-update (1.3.5)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sanitize (2.0.3)
sinatra (1.3.2, 0.9.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
sunspot (1.3.3)
sunspot_rails (1.3.3)
thin (1.3.1)
tilt (1.3.3)
yui-compressor (0.9.6)
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7-p249 & Rails 2.3.14.

I followed the documentation as closely as possible. I have done this a number of times as well (I know the definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result `:)`).

Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Try uninstalling one of your rack gem and then try installing document cloud, gem uninstall rack -v=1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You have a newer version of Rack than Rails 2.3 allows (specifically ActionPack, which is a part of Rails). You either have to

- Update Rails (or possibly monkey-patch it with a backport)
- Modify the app to use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/)
- Uninstall the newer version of Rack:

  ```
  gem uninstall rack -v 1.4.1
  ```

The last option is the simplest and doesn't require modifying the app, but it prevents you from installing a newer version of Rack. If you're using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) you could use a gemset to get around this problem with other apps.

Comment: Here's what I get when i try to uninstall:You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        rack-1.4.1
passenger-3.0.13 depends on [rack (>= 0)]
rack-protection-1.2.0 depends on [rack (>= 0)]
sinatra-1.3.2 depends on [rack (>= 1.3.6, ~> 1.3)]
sinatra-0.9.6 depends on [rack (>= 0.9.1)]
thin-1.3.1 depends on [rack (>= 1.0.0)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.

Comment: @TheVman Yes, as I noted in my answer this may cause a problem for other apps that depend on the newer version, and you'll either have to adapt documentcloud to use Bundler, update its Rails version to 3.x, or use RVM and use a different gemset for documentcloud so you can install the newer version of Rack in other gemsets for other apps. (This is dependency hell, btw, and it's why tools like Bundler were created.)